# Pass CardView info of an item to another activity

Tags: android-room, android-livedata, cardview

I'm developping a market place app for some products. In one of the activities of the app i have a `CardView` where the products are shown with their info, such as brand, name, tipe of product, etc. For that i made an object called `Product`.

Now, when a `CardView` is clicked, another activity is launched where it shows the same info described before and more other details.

So far i made the card view load the name tipe brand etc. for each individual item on the `CardView` and launch the activity where all the product info is displayed.

I need to pass the info of the Item clicked on the `CardView` to another activity where i can show all the other information of the product.

I'm ussing Room libraries.

A friend recommended me to use Live data. Thanks!

Here somo code:

Product adapter:

```
public class ProductoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductoAdapter.ProductoViewHolder> {

    private final ArrayList<Producto> producto;
    private final OnCustomClickListener listener;

    public ProductoAdapter( ArrayList<Producto> producto, OnCustomClickListener listener) {
        this.producto = producto;
        this.listener = listener;
    }
    //el activty que corresponde a cada layout de los item de la lista
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public ProductoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cv_producto, parent, false);
        return new ProductoViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(producto.get(position),listener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return producto.size(); }

    public static class ProductoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private final View mItemView;

        public ProductoViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.mItemView = itemView;
        }

        private void bind (Producto producto, OnCustomClickListener listener){

            ImageView ivFoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_foto);
            TextView tvNombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nombre);
            TextView tvPrecio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_precio);
            TextView tvDetalles = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_detalles);
            CardView cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_productos);

            tvNombre.setText(producto.getNombre());
            tvPrecio.setText(String.valueOf(producto.getPrecio()));
            tvDetalles.setText(producto.getDetalles());
            Picasso.with(mItemView.getContext()).load(producto.getFoto()).into(ivFoto);

            cardView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                listener.onItemClick(producto,getAdapterPosition());
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Product activity:

```
public class GeneralActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity implements OnCustomClickListener {


    private ArrayList<Producto> producto = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Producto> complementarios = new ArrayList<>();
    private ImageButton ivMenuProdex;
    private NavigationView nvProd;
    private DrawerLayout dlProd ;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_general1);

        nvProd = findViewById(R.id.nav_view_prod);
        dlProd = findViewById(R.id.dl_prod);
        ivMenuProdex = findViewById(R.id.iv_menu_prodex);

        getProductos();
    }

    private void getProductos (){

        producto.add(new Producto("Cuchilla Suiza","Cuchilla",
                "Eskisltuna","Encabado en asta de ciervo. Detalles del cavo en bronce y alpaca.",25,6000,"https://scontent.faep8-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/136767977_3421206694658189_1630175753886517576_o.jpg?_nc_cat=108&ccb=2&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_eui2=AeECbP_Ezm1xWnfoljYhbo81WeUbkftb86VZ5RuR-1vzpczPH0tRhrCIV_0LmsU5BDI&_nc_ohc=VqPdhfdgapEAX-QUJq0&_nc_ht=scontent.faep8-2.fna&oh=709493376ea724b54952cfc11f13611b&oe=602DF234"));

@Override
    public void onItemClick (Producto producto, int position) {
        Intent ProductoClickeado = new Intent(this, ExpandidoActivity2.class);
        startActivity(ProductoClickeado);
    }

private void rvproductos(){
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        RecyclerView rvProductos = findViewById(R.id.rv_productos);
        rvProductos.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        ProductoAdapter adapter1 = new ProductoAdapter(producto,this);
        rvProductos.setAdapter(adapter1);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android)

Comment: @rahat i alredy solved with intents, but thanks!